# Перегрузка оператора "остаток от деления" (%)

Tags: c#

Есть класс представляющий из себя массив. Необходимо для него перегрузить оператор **остаток от деления** так, чтобы на выходе получался массив из остатков от деления каждого из элементов массива на заданное число.

сокращенная версия кода, выводит ошибки:

1. Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Array.length" требуется ссылка на объект.
2. Не удается применить индексирование через [] к выражению типа "Array"

```
namespace array
{
    class Array
    {
        public bool errFlag;
        int [,] arr;
        int length;

        public Array(int length)
        {
            this.length = length;
            arr = new int[length, length];
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public static Array operator %(Array ob1, int ob2)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
                {
                    ob1[i, j] = ob1[i, j] % ob2;
                }
            }
            return ob1;
        }

        public void SetArr()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Заполните массив данными");
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
                {

                    Console.Write("Введите значение элемента массива {0}-{1}: ", i + 1, j + 1);
                    arr[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }
        public void GetArr()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Значения элементов массива:");
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(arr[i, j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("Введите размер массивов с которыми предстоит работать: ");
            int length = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Array firstArr = new Array(length);
            firstArr.SetArr();
            firstArr.GetArr();

            Console.Write("Введите число, с помощью которого будут найдены остатки от деления всех элементов массива : ");
            int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            firstArr = firstArr % x;
            Console.WriteLine("Новый массив, который состоит из остатков от деления");
            firstArr.GetArr();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Все логично, операторы являются статическими, и вам необходимо получать длину из 1го `ob1`, но не пытаться ее вытянуть из класса. А вообще приложите весь класс, ничего не понятно что за `Array`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TU1vBGdZ

Comment: может речь о **перегрузке**, а не **перезагрузке**?

Comment: вы в статическом методе `public static Array operator %(Array ob1, int ob2)` пытаетесь юзать поле экземпляра `length`, потому получаете ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы применять к классу индексирование (то есть квадратные скобки аки в дефолтном массиве), вам нужно для начала перегрузить оператор индексирования: 
`public int this[int index]` или как-то так..

В перегрузке остатка от деления, вы совершаете манипуляции над тем же самым массивом, то есть изменяете его. Выглядит это не очень хорошо. Как мне кажется, лучше создавать новый массив с результатом, а не изменять существующий.